# How to solve $(y^2+xy^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2-yx^2=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Solving $(y^2+xy^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+x^2-yx^2=0$

My attempt:
$$(y^2+xy^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+x^2-yx^2=0$$
$$(1+x)y^2 \dfrac{dy}{dx} + x^2(1-y) = 0$$
$$\dfrac{y^2}{1-y}dy= - \dfrac{x^2}{1+x} dx$$
$$\int\dfrac{y^2}{1-y}dy= \int- \dfrac{x^2}{1+x}dx$$
$$\int - y -1 + \dfrac{1}{1-y}dy= \int - x + 1 - \dfrac{1}{1+x} dx$$
$$ -\dfrac{y^2}{2} -y + \log|1-y| + C_1= -\dfrac {x^2}2 + x - \log|1+x| + C_2$$
$$ \boxed{\dfrac {x^2}2 - x + \log|1+x|= \dfrac{y^2}{2} +y-\log|1-y| + C}$$

However, the answer given in textbook is different.
$$\frac12(x+1)^2 - 2(x+1) + \log(x+1) = \dfrac{y^2}{2} + y + \log(y-1) + C$$

Is there any mistake in my work? Can I simplify my answer more?

Comment: What is  *the answer given in my textbook* ?

Comment: What is the answer given in the book? You may have to simplify your answer to match with the book answer.

Comment: $$\frac12(x+1)^2 - 2(x+1) + \log(x+1) = \dfrac{y^2}{2} + y + \log(y-1) + C$$

Comment: First sign in front of $log|1-y|$ should be positive. Second if you simplify $\frac12(x+1)^2 - 2(x+1)$ and throw away the constants, the book answer will be same as your answer. The constant numbers can be absorbed into $C$.

Comment: It is slightly inconsistent that the right side in the reference answer is not completely written in terms of $(y-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your calculations, the final solution is arrived at:

$$ {x^2 \over 2} - x + \log| x + 1 | = {y^2 \over 2} + y + \log|y - 1 | + k$$

where $k$ is an integration constant.

You can simplify this as follows:

$$ { 1 \over 2} (x + 1)^2 - {1 \over 2} (2 x + 1) - x + \log| x + 1 | = {y^2 \over 2} + y + \log|y - 1 | + k$$

i.e.

$$ { 1 \over 2} (x + 1)^2 - 2 x - {1 \over 2} + \log| x + 1 | = {y^2 \over 2} + y + \log|y - 1 | + k$$

i.e.

$$ { 1 \over 2} (x + 1)^2 - 2 ( x + 1)  + \log| x + 1 | = {y^2 \over 2} + y + \log|y - 1 | + C$$

where $C = k + 2 + {1 \over 2}$ is an integration constant.

Thus, the two answers obtained are the same only. $\blacksquare$